# Using PostgreSQL Arrayfield as ManyToMany -like lookup?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I have two models:

```py
class Authors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Books(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    author_ids = ArrayField(Integerfield())
```

I would like to be able to look about the authors of the books by doing `books.authors`. Is there some way to do this? I can't seem to find a way to do this. This database is already prepopulated with the `author_ids` so reworking it to something else, like using an intermediary table, would be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery combined with `id__in`:

```
author_ids = Books.objects.first().values('author_ids')
authors = Authors.objects.filter(id__in=author_ids)
```

If you only evaluate `authors`, this will only hit the DB once.  If you need to evaluate both the books and authors, then there is probably a better solution using a union.